# Is there a way to hit a url that exposes API with GET request and stream that data to kinesis data stream?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, qradar

I have been working to get data from API that returns data and I have to stream that data to Kinesis data stream for further processing.
I have and IAM account with specific permissions. Also do let me know what privileges should I ask my AWS account administrator?

Comment: GET api is exposed on Aws Api Gateway, when clients call this api , whatever response this API is returning should also be streamed to Kinesis for reporting or logging purposes ?

Comment: As written, your question is confusing. It seems to me that you're accessing some external API, but then @BaluVyamajala gives an alternative explanation. Please edit with a step-by-step description of what you are trying to do. Pretend that it's running on your PC rather than AWS if that helps.